# how to replace non english (a-z) characters to closest character resemblance

Tags: ruby, rubygems

let say I have words in non-english language like

```
 Tomáš
 Babätká
 Vôľa
```

and I want to replace the non-english/no-standard characters (don't know how to call them) to closest resemblance in english language

so I would get:

```
 Tomas
 Babatka
 Vola
```

so for `áǎä` I would translate them to `a` and `óôö` => `o`

is there any Ruby gem (or maybe directly in Ruby lang)  how to map non a-z characters to closest resembling character? Or is the only option for me to write entire mapping  myself ?

These characters  are usually used in non-english languages to represent pronunciation like in Czech or Slovak language.

> but not characters like in Arabic, Chinese, Japanese or azbuka set

Reason why I need it: e.g. I want to be able to generate pretty urls like
https://www.sajtka.com/category/babatka

Comment: Time to search Ruby gems. Not sure what you'll do with Ɔ or ẞ.

Comment: What's wrong with UTF-8 in your URLs?

Comment: sorry I wasn't specific enough, I was thinking about just characters that resembels a-z chars. So not Arabic, Chinese, Japanese or azbuka set

Comment: as for UTF-8 in your URLs : it's really bad for copy pasting, (e.g. someone may post a link to a old forum with charset not suporting them and you have non-functioning url) ...it's just  awkward

Comment: "I was thinking about just characters that resembels a-z chars." – `ẞ` falls into that category. It is a combination of a long S and a Z, and takes on the function of "SS". "so for `áǎä` I would translate them to `a` and `óôö` => `o`" – That is wrong, though. E.g. my name should be transliterated to Joerg, not Jorg. I will not get *offended* if it is wrongly transliterated, but I *will* reconsider trusting my data to a site that cannot even process my name without butchering it. Also note that your proposed scheme will change at least one innocent word into a massively offensive one.

Answer (score 1):

You can you ActiveSupport gem (a part of Rails) for that.
`I18n.transliterate` replaces non-ASCII characters with an ASCII approximation, or if none exists, a replacement character which defaults to “?”.

```rb
I18n.transliterate("Ærøskøbing")
# => "AEroskobing"

I18n.transliterate("日本語")
# => "???"
```

More info https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/transliterate

Comment: Thank you, definitely a good  option for Rails, but I'm looking for something lower layer (e.g in simlpe ruby scripts )

Comment: @equivalent8 you don't have to use the whole rails for this. You can simply add `gem 'i18n'` only. 
https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/blob/a29934e07c8eb7e84ace35f45b6d77cd0bfe123c/lib/i18n.rb#L276

Answer (score 1):

Found it ! (kind of... it would be nicer if it was not extending String)

https://github.com/fractalsoft/diacritics

```
String.send(:include, Diacritics::String)
"Łorem ìpsum ÐolÓr. Šit ämet".permanent #=> "lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-aemet"
```